# how do i access to a file after the current one in Node js?

Tags: node.js

With Nodejs, we know that:
`console.log(__dirname)` gives us the directory in which the executing file is located like `C:\Users\Sunni\WebstormProjects\syl\app`.

But I want to get something like this `C:\Users\Sunni\WebstormProjects\syl`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this: `path.join(__dirname,"..")`

Don't forget the import of path (`const path = require('path')`).